# Router DNS configuration

Tags: dns

Could any router experts provide feedback on my DNS configuration?
I've tried to modify using Google's DNS servers after having connection issues. ie I could only connect to major sites like Google and Apple. Everything else  timed out.

In particular what if anything should I use for the IPv6 addresses?
Also am getting a popup warning whenever opening the settings saying I have nothing configured for my WAN interface. Not sure why since it isn't even selected.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Configure WAN interface to obtain setting automatically over DHCP and do not specify manually DNS.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean I SHOULDN'T use the static DNS IP from Google?

Comment: I can't see any positive reason to use Google's DNS if your provider's DNS assigned by DHCP do the same things and located closer to you, unless you think they spoofing DNS, but in such cases it better to run your own local DNS server that gathering information directly from root DNS servers than trust to data mining company

Comment: do you or your ISP actually use IPv6? I leave everything IPv6 disabled, since I don't use it and my ISP assigns an internal v4 address to my gatway device.